# Open ASP.NET page in div using jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, telerik

I'm using below code to open a web page inside a div tag.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#popupContact").load("Wizard.aspx");

            });
```

In the Wizard.aspx page i have a telerik RadTabStrip control. When the page is loaded tab control is displayed with out any issue but i can not navigate to tab pages (tabs are not working).

If i load the page Wizard.aspx with out the jquery code, every thing works fine.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" >
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <div class="exampleWrapper" style="background-repeat: repeat;" >
    <a id="popupContactClose"><b>X</b></a>
   <b>Fill the Form</b>
        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="LoadingPanel1">
        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
        <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxPanel1" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1"
            Height="100%">
            <div style="float: left; width: 500px; ">
                <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" SelectedIndex="0" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1"
                    Skin="Sunset" CssClass="tabStrip">
                </telerik:RadTabStrip>
                <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" OnPageViewCreated="RadMultiPage1_PageViewCreated"
                    CssClass="multiPage">
                </telerik:RadMultiPage>
            </div>
            <div id="specialdiv" class="previewWrapper" style="background-image: url('images/preview.jpg')">
                <uc1:PreviewCS ID="previewControl" runat="server"></uc1:PreviewCS>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery color box finally worked for me. it's using a iframe to load the outside window and did not produce any issues.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Answer (score 7):

[`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes the rendered HTML output from the page and inserts this HTML into your selector element.

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched
>   element.

In your case, the HTML rendered with `Wizard.aspx` is nested into your `#popupContact` div.

Any server side events etc which this Telerik control uses won't postback to `Wizard.aspx` and therefore won't work as expected.

---

When working with ASP.NET WebForms and controls which require postback, I would recommend adding your `Wizard.aspx` code into a custom user control (e.g: `Wizard.ascx`) and then call this in an AJAX [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This ensures that all postbacks etc are still linked with the `ViewState`.

---

Alternatively (and this is the approach I would personally take) look at removing the use of your web controls and replace them with HTML which doesn't have dependancy on the `ViewState`.

I'm not familiar with that exact Telerik control, but I'm sure there is a way of doing this without Telerik and using HTML & jQuery. Then you can use `jQuery.load()` and reattach any event handlers in your javascript.

This will result in a lighter, more controllable, output.

Comment: To add to this - Curt has the general point right. Telerik's controls are IScriptControls, so they rely on the MS AJAX framework and the functionality it provides. So, it is these events that provide the initialization of the client-side objects of the controls that offer the rich functionality you are lookging for.

When only the markup is loaded via AJAX these events are not available, there is noone to call the $create() for each script control in order to have it work.

Go with standard HTML if you need to get pages like this (a string). jQuery UI or KendoUI from Telerik.

Or user controls

Comment: i just check the functionality on IE. surprisingly it works perfectly  in IE. Before i checked only on chrome and firefox. Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Wizard.aspx` is somehow a partial page, calling `$("#popupContact").load("Wizard.aspx");` is going to load an entire HTML document into your `div`, which is going to result in completely invalid markup. Invalid markup tends to cascade into a whole lot of other stuff not working...

It should be noted that `.load()` allows you to pull a fragment out of the result prior to injecting it - add an URL fragment with the ID of the container for your "wizard" control to the URL you supply to `.load()`:

`$("#popupContact").load("Wizard.aspx #wizard_or_whatever_you_named_this");`

You will lose any CSS or JavaScript embedded on that page, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

**iframe:** The  tag specifies an inline frame. An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.

Eg.:

```
<iframe src="Wizard.aspx" id="ifrmWizard"></iframe> 

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#ifrmWizard").attr("src","Wizard.aspx");
});
```